# DB2 STORED PROCEDURE AS400

Tags: db2

Espero me puedan ayudar.
Tengo un stored procedure:

La tabla `TABHXTPL` es del `DB2` y es un tipo de dato `L` osea `DATE`.
El stored me funciona normal cuando la variable está en duro `2018-12-21`, si se dan cuenta tiene 3 apostrofes.

Sin embargo, cuando trato de asignar la variable `SQLTEXT` de la siguiente forma:

```
SET SQLTEXT = 'SELECT FECHTP FROM FPT.TABHXTPL WHERE FECHTP = ' || V_FECHTP || ' ORDER BY FECHTP DESC';
```

Me da un error al momento de ejecutar, me parece que me faltan algunos apostrofes cuando quiero concateno `V_FECHTP`. Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FPT.TEJ051_30 () 
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
    LANGUAGE SQL   
    BEGIN 

DECLARE SQLTEXT VARCHAR (5000) ; 
DECLARE V_STUHTP INTEGER ; 
DECLARE V_FECHTP CHAR;
DECLARE V_HINHTP VARCHAR(12);

DECLARE C1
CURSOR WITH RETURN
FOR DYNSTATEMENT ;

SET V_STUHTP = 1;
SET V_FECHTP = '2018-12-21';
SET V_HINHTP = '07:00';
SET SQLTEXT = 'SELECT FECHTP FROM FPT.TABHXTPL WHERE FECHTP = ' || '''2018-12-21''' || ' ORDER BY FECHTP DESC'; 

PREPARE DYNSTATEMENT
FROM SQLTEXT ; 

OPEN C1 ; 

END ;
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error exacto que estás obteniendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que dentro de la cadena de texto, que representa una consulta *SQL*, la fecha debe estar encerrada entre comillas simples (`'`) y esto no se está cumpliendo cuando cambias de la fecha literal a la contenida en la variable.

## Cómo representar una `'` dentro de una cadena literal en SQL

La regla del lenguaje SQL es que, para representar una comilla simple dentro de una cadena literal, debes utilizar dos comillas seguidas (`''`), por ejemplo, para representar la cadena `O'hara`, como una cadena literal, debes escribirla así: `'O''hara'`. Si esta situación se da en uno de los extremos de la cadena, debes además colocar la comilla de apertura o de cierre de la cadena, por ejemplo, para escribir la cadena `where x = '`, debes colocar la literal así: `'where x = '''`.

Ya tu código hace esto cuando la fecha está escrita como una literal; sospecho que el código que funciona lo copiaste y pegaste, o lo escribió alguien más, y es uno de los problemas de trabajar con código que no entiendes.<sup>1</sup>

Ya con esta explicación, supongo que puedes identificar varias soluciones para tu problema. Yo voy a dejarte una, pero no es la única.

Cambia la siguiente línea:

```
SET V_FECHTP = '2018-12-21';
```

Por esta otra:

```
SET V_FECHTP = '''2018-12-21''';
```

Con esto, la concatenación simple te dará una sentencia válida al momento de armar la cadena que tiene el *SQL* que se ejecutará dinamicamente.

---

<sup>1</sup>Mi consejo de vida es que dediques esfuerzo a comprender el código, pues esto es esencial para convertirse en un *buen programador*.